# Program exits after taking input

Tags: c++, input, visual-studio-code, user-input

I have been going through C++ Primer Plus and I am working on the programming challenges in it using Visual Studio Code since there were weird issues with Visual Studio 2017. I have looked at a lot of other similar posts but the solutions there don't work for me. For example I tried putting a breakpoint at the main() function's closing curly brace, putting in cin.ignore() at the end before return 0. But none of that works. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int inInput;
    cout << "Enter your height in inches." << endl;
    cin >> inInput;
    int feet = inInput/12;
    int inches = inInput%12;
    cout << feet << inches << " is your height." << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;

}
```

### Edit:

Tried the solution that this was marked as a duplicate of and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you built your program in Debug?

Comment: [Googling the title](https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+c%2B%2B+program+exits+after+taking+input&oq=visual+studio+c%2B%2B+program+exits+after+taking+input&aqs=chrome..69i57.7511j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) of your question gives me the answer in the first link ;)

Comment: 1st Nothing happens when I build in debug, it just opens preferences @MichałWalenciak

Comment: 2nd the solution in that question doesn't work @scohe001

Comment: @scohe001 I don't think it's a duplicate. OP has problems with breakpoints, not with closing program.

Comment: @FourFrame It is hard for me to imagine how building a project may open preferences...

Comment: @MichałWalenciak oops meant the user settings .json file

Comment: your problem is simple. Your application finishes when it reaches the end of main, the window it was running in closes. Put a `cin >> inInput` at the end. This will make the program wait for you to type something else before exiting

Comment: @pm100 tried and didn't work

Comment: If you want to write console programs, you should run them from a console.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to launch your code and as last line (before return) I putted `cin.get();` line.
After that my window are not closing.

Also, you may add one more line of `cin.ignore();` or change existing one to `cin.ignore(2)`and it will also help you.
The reason why it closing, because after this line executed

```
cin >> inInput;
```

still `\n` is inside input buffer. So first `cin.ignore()` is only ignoring one `\n` and shut down console applciation by its natural way.

p.s. A few more ways to wait:

- [C++ Console applications exit immediately when run](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1555ce45-8313-4669-a31e-b95b5d28c787/c-console-applications-exit-immediately-when-run?forum=Vsexpressvc)
- [very basic C++ program closes after user input for no particular
  reason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560625/very-basic-c-program-closes-after-user-input-for-no-particular-reason)

It is just default mode for console application: close after finishing executing program.

Hope it will help! Good luck!

Comment: It didn't work so I add 2 cin.get(); and a cin.ignore(2); but that didn't work either